# Asrock B650M PG Riptide - no audio on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sound

I don't have any audio devices except Dymmy in settings on Asrock B650M PG Riptide. How to fix this?
Details:

```
    inxi -Fxz
    System:
      Kernel: 5.19.0-46-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
        Desktop: GNOME Distro: Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)
    Machine:
      Type: Desktop Mobo: ASRock model: B650M PG Riptide
        serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: 1.24
        date: 05/23/2023
    CPU:
      Info: 12-core model: AMD Ryzen 9 7900 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 4
        rev: 2 cache: L1: 768 KiB L2: 12 MiB L3: 64 MiB
      Speed (MHz): avg: 3082 high: 3700 min/max: 3000/5481 boost: enabled
        cores: 1: 3000 2: 3700 3: 3700 4: 3000 5: 3000 6: 3000 7: 3000 8: 3000
        9: 3000 10: 3000 11: 3000 12: 3000 13: 3000 14: 3000 15: 3000 16: 3000
        17: 2874 18: 3000 19: 3000 20: 3000 21: 3000 22: 3000 23: 3000 24: 3700
        bogomips: 177262
      Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
    Graphics:
      Device-1: AMD Raphael driver: amdgpu v: kernel arch: RDNA-2 bus-ID: 0e:00.0
      Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu
        unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
      OpenGL: renderer: GFX1036 (gfx1036 LLVM 15.0.2 DRM 3.47
        5.19.0-46-generic) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5 direct render: Yes
    Audio:
      Device-1: AMD Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
        v: kernel bus-ID: 0e:00.1
      Device-2: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio vendor: ASRock
        driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 0e:00.6
      Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-46-generic running: yes
      Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 16.1 running: no
      Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes
```